# Why IE thinks requests are crossdomain on one domain

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, cross-domain

There is a strange situation happens only in IE browser.
I have an application on the domain: http://foo.com. I have a **div class="new_item"** with click handler which sends requests to the server using jQuery:

```
$('.new_item').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#add_item').load("/ru/item/edit", function () {
        //do something
    });
});
```

All browsers works without any problem Excepting IE. It says to console:

> SEC7120: Source http://foo.com not found in header
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  http://foo.com

I don't understand what's going on? Why Ie thinks, that there is a cross domain request?

Answer (score 0):

I received this too.  Not sure why, but you can resolve it by putting the full url in:

```
$('#add_item').load("http://foo.com/ru/item/edit", function () {
```